# How to select the Parent element which is an expandable element using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I need to select the parent term[XXX Inc and not XXX Inc (Philippines)] from the DOM or html structure given below

```
 <ul class="dynamic-tree-branch dynamic-tree-trunk">
<li id="twig-18767-1zhyF" class="dt-twig dt-highlighted dt-last is-loaded is-expanded dt-minus dt-incomplete" title="XXX Inc">
XXX Inc
<ul class="dynamic-tree-branch">
<li id="twig-18821-qcfqw" class="dt-twig dt-highlighted dt-not-expanding dt-last" title="XXX Inc (Philippines)">XXX Inc (Philippines)</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

-> when I try to select the parent element using the webdriver click method,it fails to do any action.
  - I tried using Javascript executer, which expands the parent element instead of selecting the particular element.
  - I tried using Action class methods, but it fails to do any action again.

Any alternate method to select the parent element will be helpful.

[Manual Execution after Click operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6xn8.png)

[Automation result after Click operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU2a5.png)

As you can see in the above image related to automation result. parent element is not getting selected but is expanded when I click on it.

Comment: Try trimming down the `text()` you are reading from element then match it with `'XXX Inc'`

Comment: I'm able to write xpath which has one matching node. when I use the same xpath to click the element from code. It doesn't work.

Comment: Do `console.log()` and check 
whether you are getting a single element or an array through that selector?
If its an array access element by index. :)

Comment: please find the two images updated above in the description for manual execution and the automation execution after click operation

Answer (score 1):

try a more elaborate cssSelector as below:

```
ul.dynamic-tree-branch.dynamic-tree-trunk > li
```

Comment: above cssSelector performs no action with webdriver click but works with Javascript executor. I have a problem here :  please find the two images updated above in the description for manual execution and the automation execution after click operation.

Comment: What you get more items if clicked  using selenium?

Comment: using selenium,element will expand after click operation instead of getting selected. where as manually if we click element behavior is different. It will get selected without getting expanded.

Comment: `public String XPATH_HIERARCHY_SEARCH_OPTIONS="ul.dynamic-tree-branch.dynamic-tree-trunk > li";
 
 
    boolean result =selectDataFromTree(selectTerm);
 
  
 public boolean selectDataFromTree(String TreeData){
        WebDriverUtils.waitForPageUpdate(20,200);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(String.format(XPATH_HIERARCHY_SEARCH_OPTIONS,TreeData))).click();
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='treeViewSelections']/div")).isDisplayed();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

A simple CSS selector should work

```
li[title='XXX Inc']
```